# Lavaan CFA with lots of cross-loadings solution not found

Tags: factor-analysis, structural-equation-modeling, confirmatory-factor, lavaan

I am having some trouble getting my CFA to converge. There are lots of cross loadings and one factor with two indicators, both of which I think may be contributing to the error. Here is a reproducible example with simulated data (I haven't gathered the full dataset yet but anticipate n = 450).

```
library(lavaan)

# specify population model
population_model <-
  '
#create factor loadings

# Factor_A
Factor_A =  ~ .8 * X_SRR_1 + .8 * X_SRR_2 + .8 * X_SRR_3 + .8 * X_SRR_4 + .8 *
X_SRR_5 + .8 * X_SRR_6 + .8 * X_SRR_7 + .8 * X_SRR_8 + .8 * X_SRR_9 + .8 *
X_MLSR +.8 * X_ORR_1 + .8 * X_ORR_2 + .8 * X_ORR_3 + .8 * X_ORR_4 + .8 *
X_ORR_5 + .8 * X_ORR_6 + .8 * X_ORR_7 + .8 * X_ORR_8 + .8 * X_ORR_9 + .8 *
X_MLOR

# Factor_B
Factor_B =  ~ .8 * X_SRR_1 + .8 * X_SRR_2 + .8 * X_SRR_3 + .8 * X_SRR_4 + .8 *
X_SRR_5 + .8 * X_SRR_6 + .8 * X_SRR_7 + .8 * X_SRR_8 + .8 * X_SRR_9 + .8 *
X_MLSR

# Factor_C
Factor_C =  ~ .8 * X_ORR_1 + .8 * X_ORR_2 + .8 * X_ORR_3 + .8 * X_ORR_4 + .8 *
X_ORR_5 + .8 * X_ORR_6 + .8 * X_ORR_7 + .8 * X_ORR_8 + .8 * X_ORR_9 + .8 *
X_MLOR

# Factor_D
Factor_D =  ~ .8 * X_ORR_1 + .8 * X_ORR_2 + .8 * X_ORR_3 + .8 * X_ORR_4 + .8 *
X_ORR_5 + .8 * X_ORR_6 + .8 * X_ORR_7 + .8 * X_ORR_8 + .8 * X_ORR_9 + .8 *
X_MLOR + .8 * X_MLSR

# Factor_E
Factor_E =  ~ .8 * X_MLOR + .8 * X_MLSR 

# Free Covariances
Factor_A~~ Factor_B
Factor_A~~ Factor_C
Factor_A~~ Factor_E
Factor_A~~ Factor_D 
Factor_C ~~ Factor_B
Factor_E~~Factor_B
Factor_E~~Factor_C
Factor_D ~~Factor_E
Factor_D ~~Factor_B
Factor_D ~~Factor_C

# fix variance of each factor
Factor_E~~1*Factor_E
Factor_D~~1*Factor_D
Factor_B~~1*Factor_B
Factor_C~~1*Factor_C
Factor_A~~1*Factor_A

# Free item Covariances
X_SRR_1~~X_ORR_1
X_SRR_2~~X_ORR_2
X_SRR_3~~X_ORR_3
X_SRR_4~~X_ORR_4
X_SRR_5~~X_ORR_5
X_SRR_6~~X_ORR_6
X_SRR_7~~X_ORR_7
X_SRR_8~~X_ORR_8
X_SRR_9~~X_ORR_9

  '
# generate data
set.seed(432)
model_data <- lavaan::simulateData(population_model, sample.nobs = 450, orthogonal = T, model.type = "cfa")


Model <-
  ' # Factor_A
Factor_A =  ~  X_SRR_1 +  X_SRR_2 +  X_SRR_3 +  X_SRR_4 + 
X_SRR_5 +  X_SRR_6 +  X_SRR_7 +  X_SRR_8 +  X_SRR_9 + 
X_MLSR + X_ORR_1 +  X_ORR_2 +  X_ORR_3 +  X_ORR_4 + 
X_ORR_5 +  X_ORR_6 +  X_ORR_7 +  X_ORR_8 +  X_ORR_9 + 
X_MLOR

# Factor_B
Factor_B =  ~  X_SRR_1 +  X_SRR_2 +  X_SRR_3 +  X_SRR_4 + 
X_SRR_5 +  X_SRR_6 +  X_SRR_7 +  X_SRR_8 +  X_SRR_9 + 
X_MLSR

# Factor_C
Factor_C =  ~  X_ORR_1 +  X_ORR_2 +  X_ORR_3 +  X_ORR_4 + 
X_ORR_5 +  X_ORR_6 +  X_ORR_7 +  X_ORR_8 +  X_ORR_9 + 
X_MLOR

# Factor_D
Factor_D =  ~  X_ORR_1 +  X_ORR_2 +  X_ORR_3 +  X_ORR_4 + 
X_ORR_5 +  X_ORR_6 +  X_ORR_7 +  X_ORR_8 +  X_ORR_9 + 
X_MLOR +  X_MLSR

# Factor_E
Factor_E =  ~  X_MLOR +  X_MLSR 

# Free Covariances
Factor_A~~ Factor_B
Factor_A~~ Factor_C
Factor_A~~ Factor_E
Factor_A~~ Factor_D 
Factor_C ~~ Factor_B
Factor_E~~Factor_B
Factor_E~~Factor_C
Factor_D ~~Factor_E
Factor_D ~~Factor_B
Factor_D ~~Factor_C

# fix variance of each factor
Factor_E~~1*Factor_E
Factor_D~~1*Factor_D
Factor_B~~1*Factor_B
Factor_C~~1*Factor_C
Factor_A~~1*Factor_A

# Free item Covariances
X_SRR_1~~X_ORR_1
X_SRR_2~~X_ORR_2
X_SRR_3~~X_ORR_3
X_SRR_4~~X_ORR_4
X_SRR_5~~X_ORR_5
X_SRR_6~~X_ORR_6
X_SRR_7~~X_ORR_7
X_SRR_8~~X_ORR_8
X_SRR_9~~X_ORR_9



'

dm<-lavaan::cfa(Model,data=model_data, orthogonal=TRUE, std.lv=TRUE)

dm
```

And the error/output:

```
dm<-lavaan::cfa(Model,data=model_data, orthogonal=TRUE, std.lv=TRUE)
Warning message:
In lav_model_estimate(lavmodel = lavmodel, lavpartable = lavpartable,  :
  lavaan WARNING: the optimizer warns that a solution has NOT been found!
> dm
lavaan 0.6-5 did NOT end normally after 6470 iterations
** WARNING ** Estimates below are most likely unreliable

  Estimator                                         ML
  Optimization method                           NLMINB
  Number of free parameters                         92
                                                      
  Number of observations                           450
                                                      
Model Test User Model:
                                                      
  Test statistic                                    NA
  Degrees of freedom                                NA
```

Any help figure out how to adjust the syntax or model to get this to run properly would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: I get an error:
> model_data <- 
+   lavaan::simulateData(
+     population_model, 
+     sample.nobs = 450, 
+     orthogonal = T, model.type = "cfa")
Error in lav_model(lavpartable = lavpartable, lavoptions = lavoptions,  : 
  lavaan ERROR: parameter is not defined: Factor_A ~~ OR

Comment: Apologies! There were some typos from copying and pasting it over. I fixed it and tested it so the simulated data should run now.

Comment: Is there a reason that you're specifying the orthogonal argument in the cfa() function to be true? From the lavaan model syntax, it looks like you're letting the factors correlate with one another, so I don't see what is supposed to be orthogonal here. I'm pretty sure by default lavaan prioritizes the model syntax over the function arguments (so your correlated factors model is overwriting the orthogonal argument), but you might want to just double check that

Comment: If I had to guess, the item covariances are also an issue. I'd check to see whether your model works if you drop Factor_E to rule out that issue. Fundamentally, though, you have 18 items that you're saying are correlated with one another even after extracting shared covariance in factors. Factor_A loads all of those 18 items, so you're telling lavaan to find additional residual covariance above and beyond what is extracted in Factor_A. Not to mention that these items then also load on other factors that themselves covary with Factor_A.

Comment: @Billy Removing the syntax that let the latent factors correlate fixed the problem! I wanted to keep those orthogonal since this is a bifactor model, allowing them to correlate was causing the convergence issue. Thank you!

Comment: Yeah, correlated factors are a no-go for bifactor models. Glad you were able to get it figured out! Just a word of caution on the bifactor model: make sure you have a good theoretical reason for why these factors should be totally uncorrelated. Bifactor models can create deceivingly good model fit statistics and should only be accepted when there is strong theoretical support for this structure: https://www.mdpi.com/2079-3200/3/1/2 (for example)